# Kivy checkbox. Own background image

Tags: python, kivy

The issue is that when set my own `background_checkbox_normal` image it is bigger that the size I define in `.kv`. In this case it is simple red square which should be the same height as `Button`. BTW default `kivy` images works fine.  It looks like the size property doesn't change the background image size. When I set the `size` to 1,1 the `checkbox` itself is 1x1px but the red square is a lot bigger. I can't see anything about sizing of checkbox in the docu.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = """
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

Screen:  

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        height: 20        
        Button:
            text: 'Go back'

        CheckBox:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 20           
            background_checkbox_normal: 'red.png'

"""

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

[image: red square & default]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
background_checkbox_normal: 'red.png'
```

with

```
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'red.png'
                size: sp(22), sp(22)
                pos: int(self.center_x - sp(11)), int(self.center_y - sp(11))
```

## Output

[image: Result]