# Kivy CheckBox Activate Outside Designated Area

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

I have been playing around with this [post's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933515/kivy-checkbox-own-background-image) in changing the background image of the CheckBox inorder to ultimately change the [boarder/padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685505/kivy-checkbox-looks-like-solid-black-box-not-a-checkbox) - found another post, but seems that there has not been an update(?). Aside from that, I've noticed that when I create a CheckBox, the "area" that has been designated to hold the CheckBox can be used to activate/deactive the CheckBox (see image below).

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

sm = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    TestApp().run()
```

```
Screen:  

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        orientation: 'horizontal'       
        Button:
            text: 'Go back'

        CheckBox:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 60           
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    source: 'white.png'
                    size: sp(22), sp(22)
                    pos: int(self.center_x - sp(11)), int(self.center_y - sp(11))
```

[image]

All of the area shown in red can be clicked on to activate the button. Why is that? And, how do I limit the activation/deactivation specifically to the actual CheckBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `CheckBox` is within a layout class, it will take up all the available space (to itself). So if you want it to be restricted to a size just set that explicitly. Also to place it in the middle within `BoxLayout` in `orientation: 'horizontal'` you can use `pos_hint`. Thus your modified kv rule looks like this:

```py
        ...
        CheckBox:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 60, 60
            pos_hint: {"center_y" : 0.5}
            canvas.before:
            ...
```

To set custom background you can check out its [API Reference](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html#kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox).

Comment: Thank you very much! Ended up lowering the size down to `20,20` to better match the checkbox size.